# How to use the Android watchdog find deadlock position？

Tags: android, deadlock, watchdog

Could I read traces.txt to find which service deadlock?
Need I write some code in watchdog.java to find which service deadlock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading traces.txt can find which service makes deadlock.This is not a good question.
Sorry,All